# What is the recommended native JavaScript equivalent to a jQuery delegated event?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to know what is the best native js practice for a jQuery delegated event handler like this:

```
$('body').on('click','.my-class', event => {
  // perform action
});
```

Event delegation like this allows you add click events to dynamically added `HTMLElements` as you are listening to all clicks on the `body` or `document`.

Right now I'm doing something like this, which feels a little messy and sometimes it breaks if the user clicks an svg for instance. Also, it becomes difficult when you want to target multiple classes in a rather long `HTMLElement.classList` eg `'.my-main-class.my-temp-class'`.

```
document.body.addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (event.target.classList.contains('my-class')) {
    // perform action
  }
});
```

Even an NPM dom helper library that I could import would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a demo javascript function to check if element has multiple classes using the `class` attribute and not the `classList`

```js
document.body.addEventListener('click', function(e){

  console.log('Does element have classes my-class and svg - ' + e.target.hasClasses('my-class svg'));
  
  console.log('Does element have class my-class - ' + e.target.hasClasses('my-class'));
  
});
      
Element.prototype.hasClasses = function(classes) {
    // get element classses string
    var elementClass = this.getAttribute('class');
    
    // return false if class is not set at all
    if(elementClass == null) return false;
    
    // check if this class is found in elementClass string
    return classes.split(' ').reduce(function(acc, current){
      return Boolean(acc && ~elementClass.indexOf(current));
    }, true);
    
};
```

```html
<button class="my-class">I have my-class</button>
<br/>
<p class="not-valid some-other">I have not-valid and some-other classes</p>
<br/>
<svg width="100" height="100" style="background-color:blue;" class="my-class svg">
  <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" class="circle class"/>
</svg>
```

*NOTE*

*Take care with the svg. Try to click on the blue background and inside the circle to see the difference*

Comment: Nice extension of `Element`. Will test this out.

Comment: Thanks I hope it will be useful for you, but take care with the `<svg>` they are tricky :)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it:

**Edit**: Updated to handle dynamically added elements

```js
// Handle clicks
function clickHandler(event)
{
  console.log(event.target.id);
}
// Handle  dynamic element changes
function domchangeHandler(mutations) 
{
  console.log("changed");
  var eList=document.getElementsByClassName('my-class');
  for (var i = 0; i < eList.length; i++) {
     eList[i].addEventListener('click',clickHandler);
  }
}

// Create new MutationObserver
var observer = new MutationObserver(domchangeHandler);
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true };
observer.observe(document.body, config);


// Add dynamic elements
for (var i=1;i<4;i++){
  var button=document.createElement('button');
  button.id="div"+i;
  button.className="my-class class-"+i;
  button.innerText="Click me, I'm Button "+i;
  document.body.appendChild(button);
}

var div= document.createElement('div');
div.innerHTML='<svg id="svg1" width="100" height="100" style="background-color:blue;" class="my-class svg"><g><circle id="circle" cx="50" cy="50" r="40" stroke="green" stroke-width="4" fill="yellow" class="circle class"/></g></svg>'
document.body.appendChild(div);
```

Comment: This does not handle dynamically added `HTMLElements`. I'll update my question to be more clear.

Comment: Ok @etoxin, your question is clearer now.  In this case you either need what you already have.  Or re-register your events  each time the DOM is updated.   Either keep track of this your self, or use the "messy" mutation observer API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: When I run this here on StackOverflow (by clicking "Run code snippet"), it works. But when I try putting it in my own web page on my computer, it doesn't work even when using the same browser. Is there a JavaScript library that I need to load?

Comment: @ChristopherBottoms,  This should work without any library. (Which is sort of the whole point of the exercise).  The only thing I can think of is that the stack-overflow snippet will log to screen, but if you move the code to you need to check your developer console for the log messages

Comment: @etoxin,  I've added the mutation observer to check for dynamic changes. I don't know, you might still be better off with cortex's solution, but at least this is showing another way to attack the problem.

Comment: @visibleman Oh, a separate console. I found the "web console" (`Open Menu`->`Developer`->`Web Console`) in Firefox and can now see the messages. Thanks!